# Change installed device driver

Tags: windows, setupapi

I am trying to change the installed driver for a device using SetupAPI. The driver is already present on the PC, just not currently selected.

More specifically, I am trying undo the installation of a third-party driver for a USB composite device, and install the default windows driver instead.

I already got it *almost* working like this: First, find the device using

```
SetupDiGetClassDevs
SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo
SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId
```

to find the device.

Next, find the default USB composite device driver I want to install using

```
SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList
SetupDiEnumDriverInfo
SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail
```

Once I found the driver, I call

```
SetupDiSetSelectedDriver
SetupDiInstallDevice
```

This actually does switch the driver back, as can be observed in device manager.

However, the third party driver put the device into its own group/category, and this change is *not* undone when using my approach.

Manually selecting the standard USB composite device driver in the device manager *does* restore the device category back to USB Controllers, which is why I think my driver installation process is incomplete. What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the working installation sequence is

```
SetupDiSetSelectedDevice
SetupDiSetSelectedDriver
InstallSelectedDriver // From newdev.dll, not in a public header
```